# SQL: Joining data from table with multiple conditions where value matches

Tags: sql, oracle

Table1 has columns POS, ID, NAME, TYPE
I have been running a standard query as so;

```
SELECT POS, NAME FROM Table1 WHERE ID = 100 AND TYPE LIKE '%someType%' ORDER BY POS ASC
```

Table2 has columns POS, ID, VALUE, ROLE

```
SELECT POS, VALUE FROM Table2 WHERE IS = 100 AND ROLE LIKE '%someType%' ORDER BY POS ASC
```

I would like to combine these two in order to return to a recordset with 3 columns; POS, Table1.NAME, and Table2.VALUE...  No matter what I try with inner joins, I keep getting way more rows than I should.  Also, if the corresponding value in Table does not exist, I would like it to return a null or something so that essentially a recordset could look like this;

```
POS    NAME    VALUE
1      A       DF1
2      B       DF1
3      C       DF2
4      C       null
5      null    DF3
etc...
```

Is this possible at all?

Comment: What if one of the two queries return more than one row, how do you want to handle this?

Comment: I think it would be fine if it returned more than one row; maybe I could order them by an additional criteria.  So there could be 2 or 3 rows for position 1 (I use these values within a script after based on the position value).

Comment: Show us the combined query that you've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be looking for a simple join. Something like:

```
select t1.pos, t1.name, t2.value
from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2 
    on  t2.pos = t1.pos 
    and t2.is = t1.id
    and t2.role like '%someType%'
where
    t1.type like '%someType%'
    and t1.id = 100
order by t1.pos
```

Please note that, if one or both of your original queries return more than one row, you will get a cartesian products of these in the resultset.

Or if you want to allow rows coming from both tables, even if there is no match in the other table, then you can `full outer join` both queries, like:

```
select coalesce(t1.pos, t2.pos) pos, t1.name, t2.value
from (
    select pos, name from table1 where id = 100 and type like '%someType%'
) t1
full outer join (
    select pos, value from table2 where is = 100 and role like '%someType%'
) t2
on t1.pos = t2.pos
order by coalesce(t1.pos, t2.pos)
```

Comment: So if it returns more than one row, I get them as separate rows which I can deal with but if the matching value in Table1 or Table2 is missing, it doesn't return that row...  I'd like it to return 4 - C - null (or something like that) so that I can still get access to the Name value even if the Value isn't there (or vice-versa)...

Comment: @trishia42: that sounds like a full outer join. I updated my answer.

Comment: That works wonderfully well! But I have one last question if you don't mind; with your first answer, if I got more than one row for a given Position, I could add to the ORDER clause a ", t1.ID" so it would sort them using an additional column in table1; is there any way to add the same to the second answer - adding it to the order clause doesn't return anything.

Comment: @trishia42: an `order by` clause doesn't filter out records... I think that you want  `order by coalesce(t1.id, t2.id)`, or possibly `order by t1.id, t2.id)`.

Comment: The way it is now is that they are ordered by position, but if it returns more than one row per position, I don't necessarily want to filter them out, but I'd like the rows for that position to be returned in the order of t1.ID2 (sorry, it's a different column than the first ID - missed the 2 the first time).  So I could have for position 1 rows returned as 1-A1-DF1, 1-A2-DF1, 1-A3-DF1 where the order of A1/A2/A3 was set by using this additional column in t1...